# Unable to access HBase Via API

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I have hbase installed over three nodes. I am trying to load hbase via spark with the help of below code.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
import json
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("*******************************")
    sc = SparkContext(appName="HBaseOutputFormat")
    host = sys.argv[1]
    table = "hbase_test"
    port = "2181"

    conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host,
            "hbase.mapred.outputtable": table,
            "hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort":port,
            "mapreduce.outputformat.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat",
            "mapreduce.job.output.key.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
            "mapreduce.job.output.value.class": "org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable"}
    keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringToImmutableBytesWritableConverter"
    valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringListToPutConverter"
    rdd = sc.parallelize([sys.argv[2:]]).map(lambda x: (x[0], x))
    print (rdd.collect())
    rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(
        conf=conf,
        keyConverter=keyConv,
        valueConverter=valueConv)

    sc.stop()
```

I am executing code as:

```
 spark-submit  --driver-class-path /usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/hbase/lib/hbase-server.jar:/usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/hbase/lib/hbase-common.jar:/usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/hbase/lib/hbase-client.jar:/usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/hbase/lib/zookeeper.jar:/usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol.jar:/usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/spark2/examples/jars/scopt_2.11-3.3.0.jar:/home/tanveer/spark-examples_2.10-1.1.0.jar --conf spark.ui.port=5054  --master local[2] /data/usr/tanveer/from_home/spark/hbase_outputformat.py HBASE_MASTER_ip row1 f1 q1 value1
```

But the job stucks and doesn't proceed. Below is the snapshot:

[image]

As per some previous threads I tried changing /etc/hosts to comment localhost line but it didn't worked.

Requesting your help.

Answer (score 0):

On further debugging I referred to below blog post from Hortononworks link for best practice:

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/4091/hbase-client-application-best-practices.html

I have added hbase configuration file to driver class path and ran the code and it worked perfectly fine.

Modified spark-submit can be viewed as:

```
 spark-submit  --driver-class-path /usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/hbase/lib/hbase-server.jar:/usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/hbase/lib/hbase-common.jar:/usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/hbase/lib/hbase-client.jar:/usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/hbase/lib/zookeeper.jar:/usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol.jar:/usr/iop/4.3.0.0-0000/spark2/examples/jars/scopt_2.11-3.3.0.jar:/home/tanveer/spark-examples_2.10-1.1.0.jar:**/etc/hbase/conf** --conf spark.ui.port=5054  --master local[2] /data/usr/tanveer/from_home/spark/hbase_outputformat.py host row1 f1 q1 value1
```